# Why does it only calculate the first line of the function and not the rest?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>


using namespace std;

/*
Function Name: weightConv
Purpose: To take the weight and convert the following number to the coressponding weight unit
Return : 0
*/
  double weightConv(double w, string weightUnit)
{
     if (weightUnit == "g" , "G" )
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 0.035274 << "oz";
    else if (weightUnit == "oz", "OZ", "oZ" , "Oz")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w / 28.3495 << "g";
    else if (weightUnit == "kg", "KG", "Kg" , "kG")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 2.20462 << "lb";
    else if (weightUnit == "lb" , "LB" , "Lb" , "lB")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w / 0.453592 << "kg";
    else if (weightUnit == "Long tn" , "LONG TN")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 1.12 << "sh tn";
    else if (weightUnit == "sh tn" , "SH TN")
        cout << " Mass = " << w / 0.892857 << " Long tons";
    else
        cout << "Invalid unit of measurement";

    return 0;
}// end of weightCov function


int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {

        double mass;
        string unitType;
        cout << "Enter a mass and its unit type indicator(g,kg,lb,oz,long tn,or sh tn)" << endl;
        cin >> mass >> unitType;


        // case insensitive strings
        //regex reg_icase("g", regex::icase);
        //if (regex_match("G", reg_icase))

            // Output Results
            cout << weightConv(mass, unitType) << endl;

    }// end of for loop
}// end of main
```

When I enter a number and the corresponding weight unit it will only do the first line of the weightConv function of the if statement, even if I was to do 25kg it would still return "oz" instead of "lb". Can anyone explain?

Comment: Please look up your c++ documentation for the comma operator.

Comment: c++ comparisons don't work like this. In your if statements you instead will have to do: `if (weightUnit == "g" || weightUnit == "G" )`

Comment: Actually, the comparison should be: `if (toupper(weightUnit) == 'G')` or `if (tolower(weightUnit) == 'g')`  having comparisons of every letter case is a sign of bad design.

Comment: Convert your string variable to all lower case or all upper case before comparing.  Search the internet for "c++ transform toupper".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (weightUnit == "g" , "G" )`  means `if ("G" )` which is always true.  What you need to do is use the or operator `||`.  that will look like:

```
if (weightUnit == "g" || weightUnit == "G" )
```

The same goes for the rest of your if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to write

```
if ((weightUnit == "g") || (weightUnit == "G"))
```

instead of

> `if (weightUnit == "g" , "G" )`

The comma operator will always yield `"G"` as being tested against `weightUnit`.

Another way of doing this is

```
if (!weightUnit.empty() && (std::tolower(weightUnit[0]) == `g`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your if statements to:

```
if (weightunit == "g" || weightunit == "G")
```

and so on.  The problem is that what your statement is doing is first calculating the result of `weightunit == "g"`, then the result of `"G"`.  In C/C++, all statements which are neither zero nor a `bool` with a value of false are considered true, and the value of "G" is the pointer address the character array is being stored in, which is not zero, so it evaluates true.